# Wrap multiple tags with TinyMCE custom format

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, visual-composer

I'm using the php API of TinyMCE and I want to wrap multiple tags like :

```
<p>text content :</p>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```

What I have :

```
<div class="custom">
 <p>text content :</p>
</div>
<ul>
 <div class="custom">
  <li>text</li>
 </div>
 <div class="custom">
  <li>text</li>
 </div>
</ul>
```

What I want :

```
<div class="custom">
 <p>text content :</p>
 <ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is my code :

```
td_api_tinymce_formats::add('mycustomcode',
 array(
 'title' => 'Custom',
 'block' => 'div',
 'classes' => 'custom',
 'wrapper' => true
));
```

I tried removing the wrapper, changing "block" by "inline" but I'm failing to wrap my content in just one div with a custom class.

Help me find something please,